# Validate form onload

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create an already-filled out form that will be checked on-load.

Current settings are set for onblur and on keyup.
But when I tried to do
`pass1.load(validatePass1);`, it didn't work.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8s3Hp/

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this soultion, http://jsfiddle.net/8s3Hp/3/, you will see that your two validation functions are called at the end of the ready function

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
      ...
      validatePass1();
      validatePass2();
    });
```

Your validation is now triggered onload.

Another thing preventing the demo from working was that the `form` variable was not initialized, this prevented any following code from executing. I have also corrected this in the demo and you should find it working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
//On blur
pass1.blur(validatePass1());
pass2.blur(validatePass2());
//On key press
pass1.keyup(validatePass1());
pass2.keyup(validatePass2());
```

Don't forget the parenthesis at the end of a function call.

```
pass1.load(validatePass1());
```